# Is internet necessary to run android application

Tags: android

I'm very first for Android. I just tried to run the [Hello word](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) application using emulator
But doesn't launch emulator even after 20 minutes.

My console is idle  after this:

```
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'My_MOB'
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-07-12 16:02:01 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-07-12 16:02:11 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2011-07-12 16:02:11 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device emulator-5554
[2011-07-12 16:02:13 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid }
```

my last few logcat messages

```
07-12 16:49:36.699: DEBUG/dalvikvm(447): GC_EXPLICIT freed 17K, 6% free 6320K/6663K, paused 5ms+3ms
07-12 16:53:51.885: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 16:58:51.942: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:03:52.000: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:08:16.900: INFO/dalvikvm(184): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
07-12 17:08:52.032: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:13:52.050: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:18:52.113: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:23:42.420: DEBUG/dalvikvm(184): GC_CONCURRENT freed 397K, 9% free 6696K/7303K, paused 4ms+3ms
07-12 17:23:52.161: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
07-12 17:25:05.390: DEBUG/dalvikvm(86): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1649K, 62% free 13465K/34695K, paused 6ms+8ms
07-12 17:28:52.210: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I am having poor internet connection today,is this reason ?
Any other problem

Help me to recover from confusion !
Thanks

Comment: this logcat are display that your project run normally.and one more thing is that in this hello word you not require any internet connection.can you tell me what thing are display in your emulator screen?

Comment: your emulator isn't launching or your app is not launching on emulator

Comment: That looks normal. Try restart eclipse and reload the emulator?

Comment: @scorpio,@nikki: emulator is not launching

Comment: According to this line `using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD` the emulator is running. What exactly is wrong? What do/don't you see?

Comment: so please right click on project and run

Comment: to run project press  ctrl + F11

Comment: Create new emulator and then right click on project and run. Do you know how to create new emulator if not then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you start AVD emulator separately, before you start your application to run it on the AVD. And to start AVD you don't need I-net connectivity, it's required when your application does something with external web content.

Comment: :i realized i didn't starts avd emaulater.But program is not running in emulater.please help what i am missing

Comment: explain your workflow first to get what you're missing, step by step like start Eclipse, open Window>Android SDK and AVD Manager, creating new AVD and so on....

Answer (score 1):

No Internet isn't necessary at all.
There must be something else. Did you see logcat? what does it say?

Comment: What is that logcat.Where can see it

Comment: "No Internet isn't necessary at all".We can't say like this.If application access internet then of course internet is necessary.

Comment: @Rasel : you are right but right now they are talking about HelloWorld application..so no need of Internet Connection to run this application..

Comment: in eclipse, go to `Window`>`ShowView`>`Other` then select `Android`>`LogCat`.  Here you see different log messages that your device/emulator produces

Comment: These days, Hello World probably involves an Internet connection ;-) But Chirag is right, at least his activity should be launched and come up in the emulator.

Comment: Yeah,of course depends on the application and the question was "Is internet is necessary to run android apllication".So we can't say like 'at all'

Comment: @sheikh:Thank you very much .my logcat lists number of messages. but final two messages are **07-12 16:33:51.751: DEBUG/SntpClient(86): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol**

Comment: can't be sure whether its the main issue. can you copy all the text, put it on gist.github.com and link us to it?

Answer (score 0):

This logcat are display that your project run normally.and one more thing is that in this hello word you not require any internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Internet isn't necessary! 
To see in Logcat, click Window -> Show View -> Logcat (If its not there, find in Other).
And copy paste the things which are in Red color..